# Associate checkbox with datagrid viewer value

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, datagrid

I made some checkboxes outside of the datagrid viewer and I'm trying to associate a  value of checked = true with the display of that information from the database. The database string variables have the same name as the checkbox names without the cbox at the end (i.e, X_Off_box associates with string X_Off) I've listed some of the code I have below. I used an array of the checkboxes to filter out all the true values. The button click is the function to display them.

```
    public void CheckBoxLoop()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox[] boxes = new System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox[2];

        boxes[0] = X_off_cbox;
        boxes[1] = Y_off_cbox;
        boxes[2] = Z_off_cbox;

     for(int i=0; i<=2; i++)
        {
            if (boxes[i].Checked==true){

            //return a variable for checkbox to associate with database?
            }
        }
    }

    private void show_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //string constring = "";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString= @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Sample\Desktop\My Project\My Application\My_QA_App\My_QA_App\New_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from My_QA_Data", con);
            System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            My_QA_DataDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Comment: WPF, Asp.net or Winforms?

Comment: updated my question to winforms. thanks @OmegaMan.

Comment: Is the problem associating things from a database or assigning values to checkboxes? You can replicate the database call and streamline this question without the db call. Long story short, it is unclear what you are trying to accomplish verses a *route* to get there. Seeing a SQL statement which has no column names doesn't help us at all. Rework your question, distill it to a basic example.